# Plot svm pictures using rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I am learning Rshiny. I would like to plot a picture with two variables. I am not sure how to complete this. Hereinbelow is my code:

## UI

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
fluidPage(

fluidRow(

  selectInput("var1", 
           label = h3("Variable1"), 
            choices=c("age",
                        "sex",
                        "cp","
                         chol",
                         "fbs",
                         "exang",
                         "thalach",
                         "restecg",
                         "oldpeak",
                         "trestbps",
                          "class"),
                  selected ="age"),
                 hr()

   ),  

 fluidRow(

   selectInput("var2", 
            label = h3("Variable2"), 
            choices=c("age",
                        "sex",
                        "cp","
                         chol",
                         "fbs",
                         "exang",
                         "thalach",
                         "restecg",
                         "oldpeak",
                         "trestbps",
                          "class"),
                  selected ="cp"),
                  hr()
   ),

mainPanel(
 textOutput("selected_var1"),
 textOutput("selected_var2")
 plotOutput(outputId="img")

 )   

)
```

Then the server 
    library(shiny)
source('svm.R')

```
server <- function(input, output){

     dataInput <- reactive({


        if (!input$var1==input$var2){

        output$selected_var1<- renderText({ 
         paste("You have selected", input$var1)

        })


        output$selected_var2<- renderText({ 
        paste("You have selected", input$var2)

          })
       output$img <- renderPlot({

        var1<-input$var1
        var2<-input$var2
       plot(data$var,data$var2,color=c(28,32))
      })

      }else{
     break
     }
  })

 } 


I want to solve two problems now:
 1. How could I got the plotted picture?
 2. I know there are repeat code in the UI part. How could I improve it?
```

Thanks!
   I have pushed those code to the github 
    link:https://github.com/testCodeSand/test/tree/master

The last, I attach the picture [link](http://prntscr.com/l9kguw) here to show you what I am trying to do, user selects two variable and the server uses these two variables to plot a image. The error messages I 've got e.g. 
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

```
Update: I just added reactive but it did not show any output
```

Comment: The problem is with the first line of code in the server. You cannot just call `input$___` outside of a reactive environment because they input value might change. To call inputs correctly you need to use a reactive environment like `reactive`, `observe`, `eventReactive`, or `observeEvent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code needed to produce your example, note we are using `shinyalert` for the pop-up message. I am creating example data in this example

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyalert)

# Define UI ----
choices_list<-
c("age",
"sex",
"cp",
"chol",
 "fbs",
"exang",
"thalach",
"restecg",
 "oldpeak",
"trestbps",
"class")

#Test Data
col1<-c(1:5)
col2<-c(5:9)
col3<-c(10:14)
data<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
names(data)<-c("age","sex","cp")

#Ui
ui<-

fluidPage(

   fluidRow(

    selectInput("var1", 
                label = h3("Variable1"), 
                choices=choices_list,
                selected ="age"),
    hr()  
  ),  

  fluidRow(

    selectInput("var2", 
                label = h3("Variable2"), 
                choices=choices_list,
                selected ="cp"),
    hr()
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("selected_var1"),
    textOutput("selected_var2"),
    plotOutput(outputId="img"),
     useShinyalert()

  )   
) 

#Server
 server <- function(input, output){

  var1<-reactive({input$var1})
  var2<-reactive({input$var2})


  output$selected_var1<- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", var1())

  })


  output$selected_var2<- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", var2())

  })

  output$img <- renderPlot({

    if(var1()!=var2()){
    var1<-data[input$var1]
    var2<-data[input$var2]
    df<-data.frame(var1,var2)
    plot(df)
    }else{shinyalert("Warning","Please select non-duplicate paramaters")}
    })

} 


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Tks @Chabo, thanks for your advice, I have corrected and then I 've got like this in the console "Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
  72: observeEventHandler". This is update file link https://github.com/testCodeSand/test/blob/master/server.r

Comment: @Avi That is due to what is in the if statement, I am not sure what you are trying to do there but the single `break` argument is throwing that error.

Comment: I would like to use two different variables in the plotted picture. So if two variables are the same (just in case if users selected by accident the same variable), then it would not accept. I am not skilled enough to do like if var1 is selected, then the select box 2 will hide variable 1. So yeah, if var1()==var2(), then it should not go further. User have to choose a different one.

Comment: Tks! I 've tried the edits. The error message was "Error in plot: attempt to apply non-function". Then I 've tried to change the plot line data$var1() and datavar2() to data$age and data$class. Then I 've got the plot picture. see the link https://prnt.sc/l9mo5o FYI, age, class, cp, sex, chol are column names. I 've tried to assign them to var1 and var2 after user selected it. But it seems not work. To get a better understanding, please take a look on datasets link https://github.com/testCodeSand/test/tree/master/datasets. Thank you so much for your help!. Avi

Comment: @Avi, the new edits to the `output$img` should work for you

Comment: I appreciate for your time. I 've tried the edited version. It works good. However, when I tried to select a different variable,  the picture did not regenerate. It remains the default version, var1=age, var2=cp. So the picture did not change. I google a new solution from this link https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html. It solved the problem partly. Now the question is: 1. If user selected the same variable, the else output text did not show. 2. The Go button seems useless.The picture already regenerated after I selected a new variable.

Comment: 3. In the UI part, I commented out  #plot(randomVals()), that came from the rshiny tutorial link. But in my edited code, I did not call it. It did not function when call plot(randomVals()) or plot(randomVals(df)). Any comments? Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I am quite happy with the result alreay.

Comment: I have updated my code and tried to upload to the shiny.io. I think I should separate the question. I will paste a link here for that question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971349/deploy-rshiny-app-to-shinyapps-io-got-disconnected-immediately But thanks very much for the help. Otherwise I could not get the most recent solutions.

Comment: @Avi The go button is "useless" because the answer above is reactive and changes the plots when the variables are changed. There was no action button in the original post, so I made the answer not dependent on one. If you want to add a warning message in the else you will need a shiny JS or shinyAlert, since `print(..)`  prints to the console, not the application, but this will be addressed in your new question. Again the picture should regenerate when selecting new variables, so double check your code.

Comment: @Avi I have posted the full reproducible code along with an alert system for when the user selects the same variable. Hopefully this clears up any confusion.

Comment: @ChaboThanks. Maybe my credit is not enough to upvote your solution this time.  But that solve exactly the problem. https://prnt.sc/l9yaxl  :-)

Comment: @Avi Glad I could help, you can select this as the answer if you feel it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

## UI

library(shiny)

## Define UI

```
fluidPage(

fluidRow(

  selectInput("var1", 
            label = h3("Variable1"), 
            choices=c("age",
                      "sex",
                      "cp",
                      "chol",
                      "fbs",
                      "exang",
                      "thalach",
                      "restecg",
                      "oldpeak",
                      "trestbps",
                      "class"),
             selected ="age"),
   hr()

 ),  

fluidRow(

   selectInput("var2", 
            label = h3("Variable2"), 
            choices=c("age",
                      "sex",
                      "cp",
                      "chol",
                      "fbs",
                      "exang",
                      "thalach",
                      "restecg",
                      "oldpeak",
                      "trestbps",
                      "class"),
             selected ="cp"),
              hr()
```

),

```
mainPanel(
  textOutput("selected_var1"),
  textOutput("selected_var2"),
  plotOutput(outputId="img"),
  hr(),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  textOutput(outputId="info")

)
```

) 
#

## Server

library(shiny)
 source('svm.R')

server <- function(input, output){

```
randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  runif(data[input$var1], data[input$var2])
})


#Assign reactive variables
var1<-reactive({input$var1})
var2<-reactive({input$var2})

#Output reactive variables
output$selected_var1<- renderText({ 
  paste("You have selected", var1())
})
hr()
output$selected_var2<- renderText({ 
  paste("You have selected", var2())
})

output$img <- renderPlot({

    if(var1()!=var2()){
      var1<-data[input$var1]
      var2<-data[input$var2]
      df<-data.frame(var1,var2)
      plot(df,col=c(28,32))
      #plot(randomVals())
}else{
  output$Info<-renderText("Please select a different variable")
 }
})
}
```

Comment: An updated version. But when the user selects two same variables, it should show a text like " please select a different variable". The code above seems not generate such a text.